# How to make 1 on/off button with getelementsbyclassname (to get array)

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

It's my first question and i'm still new in programming.
I've found the almost same alternate but i still can't make it working.

I need to make multiple on/off button in Admin Page which can make active(on) or inactive(off) article in Customer Page, change the text into On or Off, and change the style. It was working good when I used getElementById for 1 button, but I tried to make multiple buttons and used getElementsByClassName that all goes wrong.

Here are the codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onoff(){
  var currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
  if(currentvalue == "Off"){
    document.getElementById("onoff").value="On";
    $("#onoff").addClass("on");
    $("#onoff").removeClass("off");
  }else{
    document.getElementById("onoff").value="Off";
    $("#onoff").addClass("off");
    $("#onoff").removeClass("on");}}
</script>

<body onload="onoff();">
<input type="button" name="stat" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="onoff();" class="button-round blarge-round fright">
</body>
```

The CSS ones:

```
<style type="text/css">
.button-round{
border: none;
border-radius: 30px;
margin-right: 10px;}
.on{
background-color: #914b38;
color: #000;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;}
.off{
background-color: #1a1a1a;
color:#a2a1a1;
cursor: pointer;}
.blarge-round{
padding: 10px 8px;
font-size: 20px;}
.fright{float: right;}
</style>
```

Really need helps. It's for my task.
Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

Here are the codes when I used getelementsbycalssname:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onoff(){
  var currentvalue = document.getElementsByClassName("onoff").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < currentvalue.length; i++) {
    currentvalue[i];
    if(currentvalue == "Off"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("onoff").value="On";
    $(this).addClass("on");
    $(this).removeClass("off");
  }else{
    document.getElementsByClassName("onoff").value="Off";
    $(this).addClass("off");
    $(this).removeClass("on");
  }
  };
}
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<body onload="onoff();">
<input type="button" name="stat" value="On" onclick="onoff();" class="onoff button-round blarge-round fright">
<input type="button" name="stat" value="On" onclick="onoff();" class="onoff button-round blarge-round fright">
</body>
```

Sorry if wrong. I'm really still newbie.

Comment: where is the getElementByClassName version?

Comment: Post the code where you made use of `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, since you're already using jQuery:

```
function onoff(){
    // 'this' is the clicked button,
    // 'toLowerCase()' is to ensure case insensitivity:
    var currentState = this.value.toLowerCase(),
        // setting the new state (on/off) based on the
        // current state:
        newState = currentState === 'on' ? 'Off' : 'On';
    // setting the value to the new state,
    // toggling the class from on to off (or vice versa):
    $(this).val(newState).toggleClass('on off');
}

// selecting all elements with the relevant class,
// binding a click handler to execute the function:
$('.onoff').click(onoff);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a3uCE/1/).

Plain JavaScript alternative (note: this approach requires an up-to-date browser):

```
// extending the prototype of HTMLInputElements, in order to allow chaining the method:
HTMLInputElement.prototype.toggle = function (states){
    // setting defaults if alternative states aren't provided:
    states = 'undefined' == typeof states ? ['on','off'] : states;
    // retrieving the current state using 'toLowerCase()' for case-insensitivity:
    var currentState = this.value.toLowerCase(),
        // if the current state is the first state from the array we switch to
        // the second, and vice-versa (again using toLowerCase() for case-insensitivity):
        newState = currentState == states[0].toLowerCase() ? states[1] : states[0];
    // updating the value:
    this.value = newState;
    // removing the currentState from the classList:
    this.classList.remove(currentState);
    // adding the newState to the classList:
    this.classList.add(newState.toLowerCase());
}

// getting a nodeList/collection of all elements with the 'onoff' class-name:    
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.onoff');

// iterating over that collection (using Array.prototype.forEach):    
[].forEach.call(buttons, function(a){
    // a is the specific element on this iteration,
    // addEventListener binds a click-handler:
    a.addEventListener('click', function(){
        // a is still the same specific element, chaining the toggle method:
        a.toggle();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a3uCE/3/).

And, finally, a version that should be backwards-, and cross-, compatible with Internet Explorer (I think):

```
function valueToggle(states, event) {

    // defining the defaults for the states, if none are provided:
    states = 'undefined' == typeof states ? ['on','off'] : states;

    // defining the targeted element as the element that was clicked,
    // the latter part (following '||') is for Internet Explorer:
    var elem = event.target || window.event.srcElement,
        // gets the current state:
        currentState = elem.value.toLowerCase(),
        // determines the new state:
        newState = currentState == states[0].toLowerCase() ? states[1] : states[0],
        // a string containing the current classes of the element:
        curClasses = elem.className,
        // a regular expression looking for a class-name equal to 
        // the current state surrounded by a word-break (spaces, punctuation, etc...):
        reg = new RegExp("\\b" + currentState + "\\b");

    // updating the value:        
    elem.value = newState;
    // if the regular expression finds a match in the className string,
    // we replace that occurrence with the new state, or if it's not found
    // we add that new state/class (along with a space separator) to the classes:
    elem.className = reg.test(curClasses) ? curClasses.replace(reg, newState.toLowerCase()) : curClasses + ' ' + newState.toLowerCase();
}

// gets elements of the 'onoff' class (this is not supported in early IE, though):
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('onoff');

// iterates over each of the elements in that returned nodeList:    
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++){
    // using 'onclick' (for backwards compatibility):
    buttons[i].onclick = function(e){
        // the 'e' is the event,
        // calling the function:
        valueToggle(['On','Off'], e);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a3uCE/6/).

Note that in this approach, because of the difference between IE, and other browsers, handles the events object it seems to be necessary to ensure that the `states` parameter is passed to the function (though that's largely because I didn't have time to set up error-handling should it not be present, which would involve checking, in Chrome for example, that the passed-in parameter was an event rather than an array, I think).

References:

- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Conditional operator](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator.html).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
  - [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
  - [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
  - [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
  - [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Wow! Thanks David Thomas. It's really working and the explaination so clear.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help (though I might put together a plain JavaScript version as well, for completeness, if I have some free time later).

Comment: Wow, that would be great! You're really helpful. I get much information from your answer. Thanks again man.

Comment: Gee, thanks. Wow, what a very kind of you. Thanks a lot David.

Comment: And again, it's working. 'cause I've tried to make the style change but still not working. Thanks man.